# What is a good, default backend for matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I've decided to setup a custom `matplotlibrc`, and thus I need to pick a backend for `matplotlib`.  What is the best one in terms of not needing to install other additional packages?

I tend to use `matplotlib` via `ipython --pylab`, so I want interactive window based plots (when I don't I can switch to `Agg`).

I've tried `WXAgg`, but this requires (sensibly enough) WX.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Both `Agg` and `TkAgg` do not require any dependencies beyond Python's standard library.

I have had some issues with `TkAgg` and multi-threading, so if you only need to save to files (and not `plt.show()`), I would recommend using `Agg` instead (just replace it where `TkAgg` appears below).

Either add the following line to your `~/.config/matplotlib/matplotlibrc`:

```
backend: TkAgg
```

Or the following lines to your python file:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


x = np.linspace(0,1,100)
y = np.sin(x)

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

PyQt5 is the best backend for Matplotlib from my knowledge. It allows all the edits even after you run your program.
To use it,

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')
```

put this first before calling

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

#### N.B. you need to install PyQt5

for installation via pip, run command

```
pip install PyQt5
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer inline plots with matplotlib to plots in a separate window because it makes it easier to see what I'm doing when I'm fine tuning the Python code.

Python IDE for scientists (*spyder*) can do inline plotting. To try out this feature open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install python2.7 python-matplotlib spyder ipython # Python 2.x in Ubuntu 18.04 and earlier
```

or

```
sudo apt install python3 python3-matplotlib spyder3 ipython3 # Python 3.x
```

After the ipython prompt in the IPython console copy/paste the below code and press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key to run it.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt   
x, y = [-1, 12], [1, 4]  
plt.plot(x, y, marker = 'o')
```

[image]

Atom text editor with the Hydrogen package for Atom installed can also do inline plotting. I find the Atom interface more complicated to configure than Spyder in which inline plotting with matplotlib works out of the box. I got started with inline plotting in Atom because I wanted to use Atom to make inline plots with other programming languages too.